# The way to detect usb connection via pc

Tags: firefox-os, b2g

Is there anyway to detect pc usb connection (not through charger) to Firefox OS device at Gaia layer?

Any callback in Gaia layer also works for me.

The reason I do this because I need to handle some events once the device connects to pc through USB. However, so far I did not find any clue about it.

Comment: not sure if I understand, but cant you just use `adb devices` to check when a device is connected and go from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certified apps probably have a better way to do this but for a privileged app one approach may be to use a change listener on the sdcard - This will only work if the USB storage option has been enabled in settings.

```
var sdcard = navigator.getDeviceStorage('sdcard');

sdcard.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
  var reason = event.reason;
  //if reason is "shared" you know you are connected
  //if reason is "available" you know you are not connected
});
```

Make sure to add the device storage permission to the manifest

```
"device-storage:sdcard": {
  "access": "readwrite" //could be read only
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, my intention is to get the event when the usb connect to PC (not to the charger) . I guess gaia should have a callback to get this event.

Comment: Without enabling USB storage option, will that be any approach to get pc usb connection event?

Comment: well, I think this function is not yet implemented yet.

Comment: I do not see a way to do it in privileged apps.  Maybe WebUSB API will make it possible in the future.